# What's the difference between these method to deal with Unicode strings in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I tried `print a_str.decode("utf-8")`, `print uni_str`, `print uni_str.decode("utf-8")`,`print uni_str.encode("utf-8")`..

But only the first one works.

```
 >>> print '\xe8\xb7\xb3'.decode("utf-8")
 跳
 >>> print u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'
 è·³è
 >>> print u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'.decode("utf-8")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
 >>> print u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'.encode("utf-8")
 è·³è
```

I'm really confused with how to display a Unicode string normally. If I have a string like this:
`a=u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'`, how can I print `a`?

Comment: u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8' is è·³è; why would you expect it to print anything else? 跳 in escaped form is u'\u8df3'.

Comment: Your first one is the right one.  What is wrong with that one?

Answer (score 3):

`'\xe8\xb7\xb3'` is a Chinese character encoded with `utf8`, so `'\xe8\xb7\xb3'.decode('utf-8')` works fine, **which returns the unicode value of `跳`**, `u'\u8df3'`.  But `u'\xe8\xb7\xb3'` is a literal unicode String, which is not same with the unicode of `跳`. And a unicode string cannot be `decoded`, it's unicode. 
At last,<strike>`a=u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'` is really not a valid unicode string</strike>[1].

Where the `u'\xe8\xb7\xb3'` comes from? Another function?

[1]Check out the first comment.

Comment: No, it's a valid Unicode string. It's just not the Unicode string the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string like that then it's broken. You'll need to encode it as Latin-1 to get it to a bytestring with the same byte values, and then decode as UTF-8.

Comment: It's not broken. When I try `'\xe8\xb7\xb3'.decode("utf-8")`, the result would be `跳`, which is what I want. But the problem is: it becomes `u'\xe8\xb7\xb3'` instead of `'\xe8\xb7\xb3'` now.. How can I revert it.

Comment: '\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8' is invalid UTF-8.  The last \xe8 is extraneous.

Comment: @Kenji: Sure. But that's not my problem. And it's probably not all the data either.

Answer (score 0):

The unicode string `u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'` is equivalent to `u'\u00e8\u00b7\u00b3\u00e8'`. What you want is `u'\u8df3'` which can be encoded in utf8 as `'\xe8\xb7\xb3'`.

In Python, unicode is a UCS-2 string (build option). So, `u'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'` is a string of 4 16bit Unicode characters.

If you got a utf-8 string (8bit string) incorrectly presented as Unicode (16bit string), you have to convert it to 8bit string first:

```
>>> ''.join([chr(ord(a)) for a in u'\xe8\xb7\xb3']).decode('utf8')
u'\u8df3'
```

Note that `'\xe8\xb7\xb3\xe8'` is not valid utf8 string as the last byte `'\xe8'` is a first character of a two byte sequence and cannot terminate a utf8 string.